# Upper bound of sum of codewords lengths

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, huffman-coding

I need to show that for any binary optimal code for $n$-letter source the following inequality
holds:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n l_i \leq 0.5(n + 2)(n −1).$$
By $l_i$ denoted the length of the sequence corresponding to the letter $i$.

I know the bound for the average codelength $L_* \leq H(X)$. But how to apply it?

Also I know the fact that for any distribution, there exists an optimal prefix code. In my opinion, it's a key fact. So I just need to prove this fact for optimal prefix code.

Please, help me to prove the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n>1$ (the case $n=1$ is a bit degenerate). Consider the Huffman code for your source. The associated binary tree $T$ has $n$ leafs each corresponding to the $n$ letters, every interior node has two children, and $l_i$ is the depth of the node corresponding to $i$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^n l_i$ is the sum of depths of the leaves in $T$.

How large can the sum of depths over all leafs be in a binary tree with $n$ leaves? I claim that the worst case scenario is when the tree $T$ has a path of $n-1$ internal nodes starting at the root (we then have one leaf hanging of of every internal node, except for the lowest internal node on the path which has two leaf children).

Let us see why. Consider some binary tree with $n$ leaves where every internal node has two children. Consider the longest path $P$ of internal nodes which starts at the root, and let $v$ be its lowest node.  Without loss of generality I assume that this path always goes to the right child (we can always swap left and right children so this is the case). We know it has length at most $n-1$ (why?).
Suppose it has length strictly less than $n-1$. Then there is some node $u \neq v$ on the path such that the subtree rooted at its left child has at least two vertices. If we were to swap that subtree with one of the children of $v$, the total sum of depths of the leaves would strictly increases (why?). This means that the tree we started with didn't maximize this sum.

Now, we have a binary tree consisting of a path of internal nodes of length $n-1$ and one leaf hanging of of every internal node, except for the lowest internal node on the path which has two leaf children. Can you show that in such a tree the sum of depths of the leaves is exactly $n(n-1)/2 + (n-1)$?

Comment: Thank you! I understood the explanation